# Uncertainty on integrated function fitted to data

Tags: python, sampling, error-propagation

I have some data that has been fitted with a function of several parameters (using scipy.optimize.curve_fit). The function describes a two-component spectral energy distribution:

$$S (\nu) = \frac{2 h \nu^{\beta + 3}}{c^2} \left(  \frac{N_w}{\exp\left(\frac{h \nu}{k_b T_w}\right) - 1} +  \frac{N_c}{\exp\left(\frac{h \nu}{k_b T_c}\right) - 1}\right)$$

where $N_w, N_c, T_w, T_c$ are parameters to be fitted.

I am interested in a quantity that is proportional to the definite integral of this function.

$$Q \propto \int_a^bS(\nu) d\nu.$$

How can I estimate the error on this quantity?

I have the variances of the parameters of my function, but I don't know how I propagate uncertainties in this case. I think I need to do something like generate samples of these parameters, compute my quantity of interest for each set and measure it's spread? But can I just use the 1-sigma variance of these parameters to draw from a gaussian?

Comment: Only the most generic methods could be recommended based on this vague description, but if you would supply details of the function and the integral, it's likely better procedures could be proposed.

Comment: Ok, I thought they would be extraneous but I will update my question

Comment: bump - still an open problem for me